# Sort a CSV by everything after the delimiter

Tags: csv, command-line, vbscript

I have a CSV file that is in a format with "title (year)" and have written a script to convert it to "title~year" per line so it reads

```
adam~1999
betty~1983
charlie~2001
david~2004
```

I need to find a way through VBScript or Command Line to output the file sorted by date so it would read

```
david~2004
charlie~2001
adam~1999
betty~1983
```

If I could get the dates moved to the front of the line in each line then I could use a simple sort command from command prompt but I am unsure if it is possible to turn my file into

```
1999~adam
1983~betty
2001~charlie
2004~david
```

Is what I am shooting for even possible?

Comment: If you know  how to convert "`title (year)`"  format to the "`title~year`" format, then you could _know_ how to convert it to "`year~title`" one as well...

Answer (score 2):

If you use ADO, a .csv file is just a database table that can be manipulated by SQL.

Demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Const adClipString = 2

Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oDb : Set oDb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim sCs : sCs     = Join(Array( _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
      , "Data Source=" & oFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) _
      , "Extended Properties=""" & Join(Array( _
               "text" _
             , "HDR=No" _
             , "Delimited=~" _
         ), ";") & """" _
), ";")
oDb.Open sCs
WScript.Echo oDb.Execute("SELECT * FROM [31052397.txt] ORDER BY [Title]").GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf, "<Null>")
WScript.Echo "-------------------------"
WScript.Echo oDb.Execute("SELECT * FROM [31052397.txt] ORDER BY [Date] DESC").GetString(adClipString, , vbTab, vbCrLf, "<Null>")
oDb.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 31052397.vbs
adam    1999
betty   1983
charlie 2001
david   2004

-------------------------
betty   1983
adam    1999
charlie 2001
david   2004
```

Minimal schema.ini to help the provider to do its magic:

```
[31052397.txt]
Format=Delimited(~)
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=Title Char
Col2=Date Integer
```

Links: [ADO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/), [GetString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Update wrt comment:**

Nowadays, the most likely cause for the "provider not found" error is that you run the script in 64 bit mode. Look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/) for options.

Of course, the requested provider may just not be installed. To check for available providers/drivers

1. Create an empty .udl file and start it. This will open a "Data Link Properties" dialog that lists all providers and lets you connect to all accessible datasources. The nice thing: The connection string will be written to the .udl file (albeit in UTF-16 encoding) and can be copy/pasted to your code.
2. The ODBC Data Source Administrator can be used in a similiar way

[image: .UDL & Dialogs]

A quick test: Maybe using the Text driver works:

```
sCs = Join(Array( _
        "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}" _
      , "Dbq=" & oFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) _
      , "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt" _
), ";")
```

(It does for me, which shows that **not** changing a running system to the lastest hardware and OS version can be good for you)

Comment: "I get a Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed." Error at line 16 Character 1. When I try your script... Am I missing something?